# How to find the prefix of the bot inside a Cog when storing prefix in a json file

Tags: discord.py

I want to have my Discord bot reply to a ping. And I would like to add the prefix of the bot along with the reply.

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_message(self, message= str):

  with open('prefixes.json', 'r') as f:
    prefixes=json.load(f)
  prefix=prefixes[str(self.guild.id)]
  
  #reply to a ping
  if self.bot.user.mentioned_in(message):
      await message.channel.send(f'Hey there, my prefix is `{prefix}`. Please enter `{prefix}help` for a more detailed overview!')
```

The error I'm getting:
AttributeError: 'Events' object has no attribute 'guild'

Comment: I believe you're trying to typehint `message` as a `str` there, for reference to typehint you use a `:`, not an `=` so it's `message: str` instead of `message= str`. Also, the message is a `discord.Message` instance, **not a string**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self,message):
        with open('prefixes.json', 'r') as f:
            prefixes = json.load(f)

        prefix = prefixes[str(message.guild.id)]

        if self.bot.user.mentioned_in(message):
            await message.channel.send(f'My prefix is `{prefix}`')
```

Your mistake was to use `self.guild.id`. In this case it's `message.guild.id`.

You also don't need to assign a value to the variable `message`.

I hope this helped